# Connecting react native and node js

Tags: node.js, react-native

how do call an api running on localhost from react native.I am using expo cli and running the app on real device using expo app.I tried fetch("https://localhost:3000") but that doesn't work pls help!!

Network Error
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:14 in createError
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:84:24 in handleError
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0):

try to change **https to http** make sure your server is running on port 3000.

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000").then((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Tried that but shows this error                                                                                                    Network Error
   at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:14 in createError
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:84:24 in handleError
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent

Comment: ohh, your emulator is a different machine from your local dev computer. you can use http://10.0.2.2:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000